# what are possible ways of referring to a git stash?

Tags: git, git-stash

In

`git stash show stash@{x}`

what values can x take(apart from the whole numbers pointing to the serial number of the stash)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only values I know of are the one listed by:

```
git stash list
```

Ie the "whole numbers" you are referring in your question (0, 1, 2, ...), or time-based syntax:

[`git stash` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-stash):

> The latest stash you created is stored in `refs/stash`; older stashes are found in the reflog of this reference and can be named using the usual reflog syntax
>   (e.g. `stash@{0}` is the most recently created stash, `stash@{1}` is the one before it,
>   **`stash@{2.hours.ago}` is also possible**).

If so, the list of values are part of the ones specified in [`git rev-parse`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-rev-parse), mainly inspired from the following two categories:

> - A ref followed by the suffix `@` with a **date specification** enclosed in a brace pair (e.g. `{yesterday}`, `{1 month 2 weeks 3 days 1 hour 1 second ago}` or `{1979-02-26 18:30:00}`) to specify the value of the ref at a prior point in time.
>     This suffix may only be used immediately following a ref name and the ref must have an existing log (`$GIT_DIR/logs/<ref>`).
>     Note that this looks up the state of your local ref at a given time; e.g., what was in your local master branch last week.
> - A ref followed by the suffix `@` with an **ordinal specification** enclosed in a brace pair (e.g. `{1}`, `{15}`) to specify the `n-th` prior value of that ref.
>     For example `master@{1}` is the immediate prior value of master while `master@{5}` is the 5th prior value of master.
>     This suffix may only be used immediately following a ref name and the ref must have an existing log (`$GIT_DIR/logs/<ref>`).

Answer (score 0):

`git show stash@{0}` shows you the stash entry's sha1, should be absolutely unique.